# Tkinter Swapping Windows in function

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have been searching for examples of this for awhile as it has me stuck. I am trying to create a simple application to bunch a few scripts together to automate some boring stuff for my work. The issue I am facing is that once the first script runs I ask the app to swap windows so the second is displayed allowing me to input my parameters for that part of the script, however upon finishing the first script nothing happens, I get no error but also I get no swap.

All examples I found require you to change the window on button press but I do not want this. The button calls the script method which in turn when finished calls the show_frames method.

I'm pretty sure the issue is with the way I'm calling the show_frames, if anyone could help and point me into the correct direction I'd be very great-full.

I would also like to note this is my first OOP based TKinter app my others have not been OOP based.

Relevant Code:

```
class bossinit(tk.Tk):
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

    tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self,default="hieta_icon.ico")
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.frames = {}

    for F in (RenamePage,ProcessPage):
        frame = F(container,self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")
    #frame = RenamePage(container,self)
    #self.frames[RenamePage] = frame
    #frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")
    self.show_frame(RenamePage)
def show_frame(self,cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()

class RenamePage(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    ttk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

    self.v1 = tk.StringVar()
    v2 = tk.StringVar()

    title1 = ttk.Label(self,text="Re-naming Parameters:")
    title1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
    self.dirLabel = ttk.Label(self,text="Working Directory:")
    self.dirLabel.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
    self.wdDirRe = ttk.Entry(self,width=40)
    self.wdDirRe.config(state='readonly')
    self.wdDirRe.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=10)
    findDirBut = ttk.Button(self,text="...",command=self.findWdDirectory)
    findDirBut.grid(row=1,column=3,padx=10,pady=10)
    startNumLbl = ttk.Label(self,text="Start Number:")
    startNumLbl.grid(row=1,column=4,padx=10,pady=10)
    self.startNumEnt = ttk.Entry(self,width=5)
    self.startNumEnt.grid(row=1,column=5,padx=10,pady=10)

    label = ttk.Label(self,text="Output Directory:")
    label.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
    self.outDir = ttk.Entry(self,width=40,textvariable=v2)
    self.outDir.config(state='readonly')
    self.outDir.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=10,columnspan=2)
    button = ttk.Button(self,text="...",command=self.findOutDirectory)
    button.grid(row=2,column=3,padx=10,pady=10)
    label = ttk.Label(self,text="End Number:")
    label.grid(row=2,column=4,padx=10,pady=10)
    self.endNumEnt = ttk.Entry(self,width=5)
    self.endNumEnt.grid(row=2,column=5,padx=10,pady=10)
    label = ttk.Label(self,text="Write Start:")
    label.grid(row=3,column=4,padx=10,pady=10)
    self.writeNumEnt = ttk.Entry(self,width=5)
    self.writeNumEnt.grid(row=3,column=5,padx=10,pady=10)
    label = ttk.Label(self,text="Prefix:")
    label.grid(row=3,column=0,pady=10)
    self.prefix = ttk.Entry(self,width=5)
    self.prefix.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=10)
    label = ttk.Label(self,text="Suffix:")
    label.grid(row=3,column=2,pady=10)
    self.suffix = ttk.Entry(self,width=5)
    self.suffix.grid(row=3,column=3,pady=10)

    var = False
    progressBar = ttk.Progressbar(self,orient="horizontal",length=300,mode="determinate")
    progressBar.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=10,pady=10,columnspan=2)
    check = ttk.Checkbutton(self,text="Run defaults",variable=var)
    check.v = var
    check.grid(row=4,column=2,padx=30,pady=10)
    button = ttk.Button(self,text="Run",width=20,command=self.run)
    button.grid(row=4,column=4,padx=10,pady=10,columnspan=2)
def run(self):
    print("- - - RUN - - -")
    #print(controller.validate(self))
    print(self.validate)
    if(self.validate() == True):
        ##Script Code
    else:
        print("Validated - Not Acceptable")

    lambda: controller.show_frame(ProcessPage)
```

Cheers for any help!

Comment: I just added "" around ProcessPage in:  .show_frame(ProcessPage) but this made no difference.

Comment: use `print()` to see what's going on in program - which part is executed, what values are in varaibles, etc. This way you can find problem

Comment: why do you use `lambda` ??? It creates function but it doesn't execute it.

Comment: @furas as mentioned, it runs completely up until the show_frames as thats as far as my program has been coded. So it gets up to there but no change within the GUI.

Comment: remove `lambda:`, Keep only `controller.show_frame(ProcessPage)`

Comment: @furas I added Lambda as I'm calling it from a function. Like I side I think thats the incorrect part. If I remove lambda though I cannot call the function because it gives 'controller' not defined. This is probably the issue, an issue with scope. But how do I allow my function to call another function within the root?

Comment: you need `self.controller` in all methods.

Comment: @furas let me add some more code to my question to maybe make it more clear on the structure

Comment: I don't see `controller` in your code - you need add this part with `controller`

Comment: @furas self.controller also flags an error

Comment: better show all code - now we can't resolve problem.

Comment: @furas Yeah my bad, I didnt realise what would be relevant, I thought I would have made a simple one lined error or something. More code added.

Comment: you have `def __init__(self, parent, controller):` with `controller` but you have to do `self.controller = controller` in `__init__` - and then you can use `self.controller.show_frame(ProcessPage)` in other methods.

Comment: BTW: your class `RenamePage(tk.Frame):` is base on `tk.Frame`, not `ttk.Frame` so it makes no sense to use `ttk.Frame.__init__`

Comment: Thank you very much mate! I would like you to write it in an answer format so I can mark it as the answer for you :)

Comment: Yeah I was testing with it, one more question, you see how I have only defined entrys and widgets I need info from as self.x is this good convention? or is there something else I should do.

Comment: if you need access to widget in other methods or outside of class then you need `self.` but if you don't need access then you can use without `self.`. You can even use one short name for widgets ie. for all labels use `l = ttk.Label()` and `l.grid()` or even without variable `ttk.Label().grid()` You could add empty line befor every widget to make code more readable.

Comment: @furas Thank you for all of your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send `controllor` to `RenamePage`

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
```

but you have to create class property

```
self.controller = controller
```

and then you can use it in all methods

```
self.controller.show_frame(ProcessPage)
```